# Error when retrieving and updating data from database in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my application controller, I have a method `transaction_reimburse()` that receives ids as `POST` string values. The method's function is to get all transactions that match the ids from the database, and update them accordingly.

**Controller method:**

```
public function transaction_reimburse() {

    $reimburse = array('reimburse' => 1);
    $transactions = $this->Transaction_model->get_these_ids($this->input->post('ids'));
    $this->Transaction_model->reimburse_these($transactions, $reimburse);

}
```

**Model method:**

```
function get_these_ids($ids) {

    $this->db->select('tbl_user.name as uname, tbl_transactions.participant_id as pid, tbl_transactions.card_number as card_no, tbl_transactions.group as ugroup, tbl_toilet.name as utoilet, tbl_transactions.amount_paid as u_amount, tbl_transactions.toilet_price as t_price, tbl_transactions.reimburse_amount as r_amount, tbl_transactions.details as u_details');
    $this->db->from('tbl_transactions');
    $this->db->join('tbl_user', 'tbl_user.participant_id = tbl_transactions.participant_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_toilet', 'tbl_toilet.toilet_code = tbl_transactions.toilet_code', 'left');
    $this->db->where("tbl_transactions.id IN (". $ids .")");
    return $this->db->get();

}
```

**Model method:**

```
function reimburse_these($transactions, $reimburse) {

    $this->db->select('tbl_user.name as uname, tbl_transactions.participant_id as pid, tbl_transactions.card_number as card_no, tbl_transactions.group as ugroup, tbl_toilet.name as utoilet, tbl_transactions.amount_paid as u_amount, tbl_transactions.toilet_price as t_price, tbl_transactions.reimburse_amount as r_amount, tbl_transactions.details as u_details');
    $this->db->from('tbl_transactions');
    $this->db->join('tbl_user', 'tbl_user.participant_id = tbl_transactions.participant_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_toilet', 'tbl_toilet.toilet_code = tbl_transactions.toilet_code', 'left');
    $this->db->where("tbl_transactions.id IN (". $transactions .")");
    $this->db->update($this->tbl_transaction, $reimburse);

}
```

**However, I am getting the following error:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered    
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string
Filename: models/transaction_model.php
Line Number: 450

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
UPDATE `tbl_transactions` SET `reimburse` = 1 WHERE `tbl_transactions`.`id` IN ()
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ipa\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

What I need to know is why do I get these errors?

Comment: What is the format of your POST ids?

Comment: can you please elaborate $ids forrmat ? array or may be other possibilites

Answer (score 0):

The errors mean that your `$ids` variable is not in a string format (meaning: `1,2,3,4`. Its probably an array). To fix it, first find out what format it is on by using `print_r($ids)` or `var_dump($ids)`. Once you know the format, use PHP functions(such as `implode()`) to transform it into strings.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` is looking for a set in the format e.g. `(1,2,3,4)`.

Either make your post values adopt the format `1,2,3,4` so that when the value is included into the query it's valid or if you're sending an array use a method in PHP such as `implode(',',$array)` to create the desired format for binding into the query..

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your both function and found that in both function you put tbl_transactions.id in where clause and ids is passed from post and hence there is no need to call get_these_ids to get ids, you already have ids in post array and hence instead of transactions variable, just use $this->input->post('ids') for reimburse_these functions.

if you surely want to get tbl_transactions from get_these_ids function then you need to use group_concat with group by in query of get_these_ids function and just return that concated id in get_these_ids function then it will work.